# Can't break the while loop in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am building a tic-tac-toe. I have almost finished it but I cannot break the `while` loop in the end. I have turned win into True.  But the `if` statement in the `while` loop is not working.

```
board = [[1,2,3],[4,"X",6],[7,8,9]]
win = False
def DisplayBoard(board):
    def printborder():
        print("+-------+-------+-------+")
    def printline():
        print("|       |       |       |")
    def printitem(board,row):
        print("|   ",board[row][0],"   |   ",board[row][1],"   |   ",board[row][2],"   |", sep="")
    printborder()
    printline()
    printitem(board,0)
    printline()
    printborder()
    printline()
    printitem(board,1)
    printline()
    printborder()
    printline()
    printitem(board,2)
    printline()
    printborder()

def EnterMove(board):
    while True:
        move = int(input("Enter your move: "))
        for i in range(len(board)):
            for j in range(len(board[i])):
                if board[i][j]==move:
                    board[i][j]="O"
                    return None

def MakeListOfFreeFields(board):
    freefield = []
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board[i])):
            for k in range(1,10):
                if board[i][j] == k:
                    freefield.insert(0,k)
    return freefield

def VictoryFor(board, sign):
    def whowin(sign):
        if sign == "O":
            print("Player wins.")
            win = True
        elif sign == "X":
            print("Computer wins.")
            win = True
    def checkvertical(board):
        for i in range(3):
            if board[0][i]==board[1][i]==board[2][i]:
                whowin(sign)
    def checkhorizontal(board):
        for i in range(3):
            if board[i][0]==board[i][1]==board[i][2]:
                whowin(sign)
    def checkdiagonal(board):
        if board[0][0]==board[1][1]==board[2][2] or board[0][2]==board[1][1]==board[2][0]:
            whowin(sign)
    checkvertical(board)
    checkhorizontal(board)
    checkdiagonal(board)

def DrawMove(board):
    from random import randrange
    while True:
        ran = randrange(1,10)
        if ran in MakeListOfFreeFields(board):
            for i in range(len(board)):
                for j in range(len(board[i])):
                    if board[i][j]==ran:
                        board[i][j]="X"
                        return None

DisplayBoard(board)
while True:
    EnterMove(board)
    DisplayBoard(board)
    VictoryFor(board, "O")
    if win==True:
        break
    DrawMove(board)
    DisplayBoard(board)
    VictoryFor(board, "X")
    if win==True:
        break
print("ended")
```

fhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh fhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh fhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh fhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: for info, adding some simple `print(win)` in your function calls, first in displayboard before the if, then in victoryfor, and so one, would have showed you hte bug easily

Comment: Some formatting improvements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `whowin` function (inside of `VictoryFor`) you simply create a local `win` variable. If you want to refer to the global one, you need to tell Python to do so:

```py
def whowin(sign):
    global win   # <---- add this
    if sign == "O":
        print("Player wins.")
        win = True
    elif sign == "X":
        print("Computer wins.")
        win = True
```